# I want to know if Ubuntu will work better than Windows XP on my Dell inspiron 1300

Tags: dell, windows-xp, inspiron

I have an upgraded Dell Inspiron 1300 from 7 years ago that my parents gave to my as my birthday present. It currently features 2 gb of RAM memory and 160 bg of hard core memory. It has a Mobile Intel 910 GML Express Chipset Family video card and a Intel Celeron Processor at 1.60 GHz. I would just love to know if by installing Ubuntu on my computer I will be able to have a better performance while watching videos and streaming stuff on line.

Comment: I would go with Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system configuration is more than enough to run Ubuntu. Yes it will perform better that Windows XP. Although I suggest you to use **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** over latest version of Ubuntu like `12.10`, `13.04` and `13.10` because:

- It is long term support and thus has support till April 2017.
- Has the feature of `Unity 2D` desktop environment which requires less resources and which is removed after `12.10`.
- Runs better than latest version of Ubuntu in low configuration system.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and my system configuration is:

`sudo lshw`:

```
saurav-p4i45gx-pe
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: P4I45Gx_PE,
    vendor: INTEL
    version: 1.00
    serial: 00000000
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: chassis=desktop cpus=1
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P4I45Gx_PE,
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.00
       serial: 00000000
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P3.00
          date: 06/01/2004
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 192KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int17printer int10video acpi usb agp ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 15.4.1
          serial: 0000-0F41-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: FC-478
          size: 2400MHz
          capacity: 3GHz
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl cid xtpr
          configuration: id=0
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: Internal Cache
             size: 48KiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             clock: 25MHz (40.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst synchronous internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: Internal Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             clock: 25MHz (40.0ns)
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 1
          size: 1019MiB
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0 memory:e0000000-e3ffffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:dff80000-dfffffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:e400(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:e800(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:ec00(size=32)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:dff7bc00-dff7bfff
        *-pci
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 82
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:dfd00000-dfdfffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: a
                bus info: pci@0000:03:0a.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 00:0b:6a:d3:7f:8c
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.11 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:17 ioport:cc00(size=256) memory:dfdfff00-dfdfffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801DB/DBL (ICH4/ICH4-L) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:fc00(size=16) memory:40000000-400003ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) ioport:dc00(size=64) memory:dff7ba00-dff7bbff memory:dff7b900-dff7b9ff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD400BB-22JH
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 05.0
             serial: WD-WMAMC4230857
             size: 37GiB (40GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=72b172b1
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: d05a6341-1161-9442-a240-105dac4defc9
                size: 10GiB
                capacity: 10GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-06-15 09:58:59 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 27GiB
                capacity: 27GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume:0
                   description: HPFS/NTFS partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   logical name: /media/40GBTWO
                   capacity: 17GiB
                   configuration: mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
              *-logicalvolume:1
                   description: Linux filesystem partition
                   physical id: 6
                   logical name: /dev/sda6
                   logical name: /
                   capacity: 8973MiB
                   configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered state=mounted
              *-logicalvolume:2
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 7
                   logical name: /dev/sda7
                   capacity: 1344MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM GH22NP20
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 2.00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

In short: `Intel pentium 4 2.40 GHz, 1 GB RAM, 64 MB Intel 845G graphics, 40 GB HDD`

I use ubuntu because of the it's low system requirement than XP and also perform better than XP. Hope my answer helps you..

Comment: Sounds good!! You are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely have a try on linux! XP including all necessary updates and Service Packs makes an old Notebook like that much to slow to use. The next big blocker is the year 2014. Microsoft will not deliver any updates for XP anymore beginning with April 9th. After that date you can be sure to get more and more viruses and trojans after security holes have been discovered in windows libraries used by newer versions and XP.

2GB of RAM should be ok for working with ubuntu/kubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu etc.... but don't expect a fast system like using new hardware.

Comment: Thank you! I will totally try it out. I just want to see videos without all the lag this computer gets.